# Upper Hemisphere Only option in Unity HDRP Cloud layer is not visible

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsvaA.png)

I find Upper Hemisphere Only option in hdrp manual.
However, I can't find it in inspector.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0NwV.png)

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.high-definition@12.1/manual/Override-Cloud-Layer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try click on the 3 dots on the right hand side...
I find "Show Additional Properties" option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).